# Access WebContent folder file in java class

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm developing a web application with sqlite database. While developing the application, I created the database connection in a java class. There I've mentioned my url as like below

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:D:\\Database\\profileDB.db";
```

I want to place the db file from that location to specific location inside my Webcontent folder say resources.

Now I want to change my URL pointing to folder file.

> Webcontent/resources/profileDB.db

.

Anyone kindly suggest me how to do this. For the information, I'm not using any servlet in creating the connection, it is just a normal java class.

Comment: The contents of a web application are generally considered to be read-only. Why do you want to embed the database inside it?

Comment: If it is a bad approach, can you suggest me how to use the sqlite database in the web app deployment.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you need to add sqlite.jar in `Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar`.

Then you can try connecting using:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("JDBC:sqlite:sample.db"); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

You can refer this [link](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) for sqlite jdbc

Comment: what is Andy.SQLite..? BTW, I was connected to the database file when it is placed in some location, now i want to use the file from the webcontent folder..

Comment: @CarlJohn Actually its the db name, in your case its profileDB.db. Its not required to add the jar into webcontent folder, by adding into project properties it should be able to resolve

Comment: I've done like your suggestion. Connection was made successfully but when i try to access the table name, it shows the table doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the SQLite database but if you just want the url to the db file the you can use getResource("name_of _the resource") method of the Class class. it gives you the URL of the named resource. the rules for searching for the resource depends upon the classloader used to load the class.

for eg : my package(folder) structure is :

```
   test-
    |-foo.class
    |-image.png
```

then inside foo.class

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("image.png");
```

it will give the url to the image.png